# ERROR: could not create replication slot "my_subscription": ERROR: logical decoding requires wal_level >= logical

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-replication

I have followed exactly what have done [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-logical-replication-with-postgresql-10-on-ubuntu-18-04).

Everything is fine until the point where I connect subcription to publication by using the command below

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription CONNECTION 'host=db_master_private_ip_address port=5432 password=my_password user=sammy dbname=example' PUBLICATION my_publication;
```

and it gives me

```
ERROR:  could not create replication slot "my_subscription": ERROR:  logical decoding requires wal_level >= logical
```

is there anyone else who faced this problem too?

EDIT
My `wal_level` is set to `logical`

Comment: There is no `create subscription` command in Postgres 9.1 - which version are you **really** using?

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. On `db_master_private_ip_address` you need to set `wal_level` to `logical`

Comment: I have done already wal_level to logical and restarted postgresql but error still exists my Postgres is 12

Comment: I am inclined to trust Postgres on this, not your claim that you did change that on the primary server

Answer (score 4):

You have to do what the error message suggests:

Change the configuration parameter `wal_level` on the primary server to `logical` and restart PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same problem. I have checked the wal_level on the Publisher machine. The value is "logical". Do I have to set for the Subscriber machine as well ? Thanks. I am using postgres 12

Comment: @padjee No, only on the publisher.